# In a figure of emmeans, indicate effect size of contrasts as "significance stars"

Tags: lsmeans, ggplot2

I have an `emmeans` object of a logistic regression model (`glmer`). I made plots with `ggplot2`, which I like very much. Now I'd like to incorporate the contrasts in some way. Is there any convention about doing this?

I was thinking of using the lower confidence limit (LCL) of the contrasts and [Cohen’s Conventions for Small, Medium, and Large Effects](https://core.ecu.edu/wuenschk/docs30/EffectSizeConventions.pdf):

| LCL | Effect Size | Stars |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Negligible | * |
| 1.49 | Small | ** |
| 3.45 | Medium | *** |
| 9 | Large | **** |

So the comparison for jv and om would receive no stars, ov 1 star and jm four stars. I added this to the figure below. Does this make sense?

## Emmeans

```r
individu = jv:
 locatie_jm     prob     SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 Kleine Oceaan 0.677 0.0616 Inf     0.547     0.785
 Oceaan        0.682 0.0546 Inf     0.567     0.779

individu = ov:
 locatie_jm     prob     SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 Kleine Oceaan 0.764 0.0517 Inf     0.649     0.850
 Oceaan        0.623 0.0587 Inf     0.503     0.729

individu = jm:
 locatie_jm     prob     SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 Kleine Oceaan 0.972 0.0097 Inf     0.945     0.986
 Oceaan        0.650 0.0572 Inf     0.532     0.753

individu = om:
 locatie_jm     prob     SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 Kleine Oceaan 0.912 0.0244 Inf     0.851     0.949
 Oceaan        0.889 0.0265 Inf     0.826     0.932
```

[image]

## Contrasts

```r
individu = jv:
 contrast               odds.ratio    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 Kleine Oceaan / Oceaan      0.977 0.292 Inf     0.544      1.75

individu = ov:
 contrast               odds.ratio    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 Kleine Oceaan / Oceaan      1.961 0.591 Inf     1.086      3.54

individu = jm:
 contrast               odds.ratio    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 Kleine Oceaan / Oceaan     18.612 6.852 Inf     9.045     38.30

individu = om:
 contrast               odds.ratio    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 Kleine Oceaan / Oceaan      1.282 0.427 Inf     0.668      2.46

Results are averaged over the levels of: voederdag, tijd_11 
Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the log odds ratio scale
```

Comment: Cohen's recommendations are (a) idiosyncratic and (b) specific to his field, which was psychology.  They are are not generally applicable in statistics.  It's up to you as the researcher to decide what effect sizes are meaningful in your application.  BTW, confidence limits have no invariant relationship to effect sizes: it looks like you might be confusing two distinct concepts.

Comment: I don't see what's really so wrong about just using P values. Yes, they can be abused. But so can effect sizes (more so, IMHO). Plus, really, I think the plot you have is quite effective in telling the story without any asterisks added.

Comment: I'm not using significance testing any longer for several reasons, and, although p-values are fine, I prefer to avoid them because many people interpret them dichotomously. Confidence Intervals are an excellent alternative.

That said, using Cohen's recommendations about small/medium/large effect sizes is again categorizing without looking at the data, which I want to avoid. So giving stars based on effect size is not what I'm looking for.

How about incorporating the odds ratios and CIs thereof in the figure?